# Зачем implements OnInit?

Tags: javascript, angular2, typescript

Подскажите пожалуйста зачем для хука OnInit в объявлении класса в компоненте пишут так:

```
export class SpeakersComponent implements OnInit {
```

Компонент работает без проблем и так:

```
export class SpeakersComponent {
```

Если же всё таки первая запись зачем-то нужна, то как быть в случае использования нескольких хуков в одном компоненте. Например OnInit, ngDoCheck, ngOnDestroy ? Как известно в ангуляре нет множественного наследования.

Comment: OnInit - это **интерфейс**, поэтому к _множественному наследованию_ тут нет отношения.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Тогда просто перечислите несколько интерфейсов
`export class SpeakersComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy....`

На самом деле перечисление интерфейсов нужно только для того чтобы помочь вам не забыть имплементировать их т.к. ИДЕ и компилятор покажут ошибку, но при срабатывании соответствующего события Angular просто проверяет наличие у объекта соответствующего метода (ngOnInit, ngOnDestroy соответственно) и если он определен - вызывает его. Он не может определить в рантайме был ли у класса указан интерфейс или нет. Т.е. ngOnInit будет вызван даже если implements OnInit *НЕ БЫЛ* указан.

https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

Answer (score 2):

После создания компонента фреймворк Angular вызывает у этого компонента ряд методов, которые представляют различные этапы жизненного цикла.
Каждый такой метод определен в отдельном интерфейсе, который называется по имени метода без префикса "ng". Например, метод ngOnInit определен в интерфейсе OnInit. Поэтому, если мы хотим отслеживать какие-то этапы жизненного цикла компонента, то класс компонента должен применять соответствующие интерфейсы

https://metanit.com/web/angular2/2.8.php

Comment: как это отвечает на поставленные вопросы?

Comment: Зачем? Чтобы использовать метод ngOnInit в коде компонента. Как быть в случае использования нескольких хуков? Как уже сказано это интерфейс и можно добавить хоть все через запятую, по ссылке есть пример.

Comment: Стоит перенести это пояснение непосредственно в ответ, наравне с цитатой

Comment: Спасибо, со вторым вопросом всё понятно. Но с первым - нет. Зачем писать то, чего можно не писать?

Comment: Если хотите использовать метод ngOnInit, то писать нужно